# Custom Paper Size, Geometry Package Class

Tags: margins, geometry

I'm trying to compile a document to a custom page size and then have crop marks printed. I can't even get to the crop package because there's a `geometry` package clash and I don't know why. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,headsepline]{bookest}
\usepackage[paperheight=7in,paperwidth=4.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{LinLibertine_Re-4.7.5}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried with the `showcrop` option of the geometry package?

Comment: Option clash with package: geometry.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `bookest.cls` does

```
\RequirePackage{geometry}
```

before the package is loaded in the preamble. So there is an option class: it has been loaded with no options and later with some.

There are various ways around this.

1. Use

   ```
   \geometry{<options>}
   ```

   in the preamble, if the options are ones which can be set after the package is loaded. If not, choose method 2 or 3.
2. Use

   ```
   \documentclass[<options>]{bookest}
   ```

   which will probably produce some warnings about unrecognised options, which can be safely ignored. Alternatively, use method 3.
3. Use

   ```
    \PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{geometry}
    \documentclass{bookest}
   ```

   to pass the options to the package when the class loads it.

## EDIT

Here's an example. Note that even with `\tiny` sized font, the text block is way too small for TeX to produce nice output. With a normal sized font, expect oodles of bad boxes.

Note that crop marks only make sense when the `layoutsize` is smaller than the `papersize` since there is otherwise nowhere for the marks to actually show. (I guess they still exist but not on the paper.)

```
\documentclass{bookest}% neither 10pt nor headsepline are doing anything whatsoever as far as I can tell - certainly the class doesn't recognise them
\geometry{%
  paperheight=8in,
  paperwidth=5.25in,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  right=1in,
  left=1in,
  layoutsize={4.25in,7in},
  layoutoffset={.5in,.5in},
  showcrop,
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tiny
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: cropped]

## EDIT

Here's an example showing the crop marks on US letter paper, as requested in comments:

[image: crop marks on US letter]

```
\documentclass{bookest}% neither 10pt nor headsepline are doing anything whatsoever as far as I can tell - certainly the class doesn't recognise them
\geometry{%
  letterpaper,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  right=1in,
  left=1in,
  layoutsize={4.25in,7in},
  layoutoffset={1.5in,1.5in},
  showcrop,
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tiny
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried the third option since it seemed to be the easiest; but the compile threw a "Missing \begin{Document}" error. Ignoring that yielded a fall-back letter size page. I tried adding the line "\PassOptionsToPackage[paperheight=7in,paperwidth=4.25in,top=1in,bottom=.5,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}" both before and after \documentclass{bookEST} (damn autocorrect)

Comment: That's because you used square brackets rather than curly ones to surround the list of options.

Comment: Making that correction, the program compiled properly, but the page size (that is, the virtual page size) is now letter size instead of 4.25x7. The goal is to produce a proof so that I can see physically the layout.

Comment: Since 4.25x7 is smaller than letter paper, it should be possible to print a page with crop marks.

Comment: Please see edit @user26732. As you see, it certainly is possible to get crop marks on US letter paper with a 4.25x7 layout. All I did was say `letterpaper` instead of setting `paperheight` and `paperwidth`. Note that since the class loads `geometry`, it may well use it and you may well need to either set `geometry` options using class options (according to the documentation if it covers this) or to override it after the class is finished its `geometry` configuration. Since `\geometry{}` seems to work here, I'd suggest sticking with that.

Comment: Note that the layout size should be the final paper size after the block is cut, including all margins etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the document class already loads the `geometry` package, and this is what causes the option clash.  Simply use the `\geometry` command to specify the options you want to pass.  For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,headsepline]{bookest}
% \usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    layoutheight=7in, layoutwidth=4.25in,
    layoutvoffset=1in, layouthoffset=1in,
    margin=0in, % am I correctly guessing your intention?
    showcrop
}


\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked. My ultimate goal was to modify the bottom margin because it was too big. I thought that the geometry package would automatically calculate the text block area, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'd like maybe a half inch at the bottom of the page with mirrored right left margins for printing.