# Force custom paper size

Tags: geometry, paper-size

I'm trying to force the paper size with LaTeX, but all I can find are solutions like

[LaTeX - how do I force PDF page height/width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/latex-how-do-i-force-pdf-page-height-width)

and

[Custom Paper Size, Geometry Package Class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313615/custom-paper-size-geometry-package-class)

in which the geometry is changed within the page instead of actually changing the page dimensions.

How do genuinely change the paper size? (For instance to 100mm by 100mm)

I use `lualatex` from `Tex Live 2017` under `Windows 7`.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=100mm, paperheight=100mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example showing the problem? I suppose you've tried with  `geometry`?

Comment: What is your problem with the first linked post?

Comment: The missing `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` was the culprit :(. With `\RequirePackage{luatex85}`, the code works fine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2018:**

As [commented by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379990/force-custom-paper-size/379991?noredirect=1#comment1058518_379991) this workaround is no longer required, as the `geometry` package was updated in the mean time.

**Original answer:**

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=100mm, paperheight=100mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `luatex85` is no longer required with `geometry` 2018/03/24 v5.7